# Selenium WebDriverWaits

Tags: selenium, webdriver, wait, explicit

In the following Selenium Explicit wait , I see the method `until` returns something like

`<V> V` for the method `until(com.google.common.base.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)`

My doubt is how they are referencing it to a element of type `WebElement`?

```
WebElement element = b.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Email")));
```

Comment: What is it you actually want to know? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in the source, there is specified:

- `@param <V> The function's expected return type.`
- The method signature looks like : `public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {...}`.

In conclusion, if you use [ExpectedCondition](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html) parameter (this is most probably), the type its parameterized type. Look below for an example :

```
    try {
      (new WebDriverWait(webDriver, maxWaitTime)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return applyCondition(driver, locator);
        }
      });
      return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex) {
      return false;
    }
```

In this case, as you can see, the return type of the method `until` it is `Boolean`, which cames from parameterized type of `ExpectedCondition` : `new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by loan, I think the question is more related to the working of generics then anything to do with webdriver.  So, reading more about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) would help answer this question.

I am not sure if the below is the best explanation, but I will try to give it a shot :

When you call elementToBeClickable method it returns something like `ExpectedCondition<WebElement>`.

The until method returns V.  V is a generic type placeholder.  So what would V hold? V is same as the one in `Function<? super T, V>`

Your case : `Function<? super T, V>` = `ExpectedCondition<WebElement>`.

Look at the definition of ExpectedCondition then,

`public interface ExpectedCondition<T> extends Function<WebDriver, T> {}`

So in your case, it is `ExpectedCondition<WebElement>` which would mean `Function<WebDriver, WebElement>`
So V is WebElement and hence it returns WebElement.